# How to retrieve previous messages with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a counting channel in my server, and I want to make a bot where it removes your message if it isn't 1 number after the previous message. I tried Googling on how to retrieve previous messages but got no results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`discord.TextChannel.last_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.last_message) to get the last message of a channel.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    c_channel = discord.utils.get(message.guild.text_channels, name='counting channel')
    if message.channel == c_channel and int(c_channel.last_message.content) + 1 != int(message.content):
        await message.delete()
```

**EDIT:**

You can use `channel.history` if `channel.last_message` is not working.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    c_channel = discord.utils.get(message.guild.text_channels, name='counting channel')
    messages = await c_channel.history(limit=2).flatten()
    if message.channel == c_channel and int(messages[1].content) + 1 != int(message.content):
        await message.delete()
```

`messages = await c_channel.history(limit=2).flatten()` returns you the last 2 messages of a channel.

If this doesn't work, then change the `int(messages[1].content)` to `int(messages[0].content)`.

Comment: I just tried this code but it turns out that `last_message.content` returns the current message because it is viewed as the last message. Is there a way around that?